# How to use NSOutlineView without bindings

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

My data looks like:

```swift
let keysDetails : [String : Any] = [
    "kAddToBag" : [
        "locDict" : [
            "at" : "add",
            "ae" : "Add"
        ],
        "jsonDict" : [
            "at" : "add to bag",
            "ae" : "ADD TO BAG"
        ],
        "path" : "somepath"
    ],
    "kShopTab" : [
        "locDict" : [
            "be_fr" : "shop",
            "be_nl" : "SHOP"
        ],
        "jsonDict" : [
            "be_fr" : "shop",
            "be_nl" : "SHOP"
        ],
        "path" : "somepath2"
    ]
]
```

[image]

I want NSOutlineView to look like above picture.

Comment: Without Bindings you have to adopt `NSOutlineViewDataSource` and `NSOutlineViewDelegate` and implement the relevant methods. And here are some [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSOutlineViewDataSource)

Comment: Raywenderlich.com has a sample project.

Comment: If you are new to swift development and the AppKit maybe it would be better to start with doing some tutorial for the NSTableView instead since it is a little simpler/straightforward and you will still learn about concepts that are valid for the outline view as well such as data source, delegate and more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Input data

```swift
let keysDetails : [String : Any] = [
    "kAddToBag" : [
        "locDict" : [
            "at" : "add",
            "ae" : "Add"
        ],
        "jsonDict" : [
            "at" : "add to bag",
            "ae" : "ADD TO BAG"
        ],
        "path" : "somepath"
    ],
    "kShopTab" : [
        "locDict" : [
            "be_fr" : "shop",
            "be_nl" : "SHOP"
        ],
        "jsonDict" : [
            "be_fr" : "shop",
            "be_nl" : "SHOP"
        ],
        "path" : "somepath2"
    ]
]
```

Dictionary is an unordered collection and it will cause issues when you'll want to access elements via indexes, ... Let's create a custom structure which will provide data for the `NSOutlineView`.

```swift
struct Item {
    let title: String      // First column value
    let loc: String        // Second column value
    let json: String       // Third column value
    let children: [Item]   // Possible children

    init(title: String, loc: String, json: String, children: [Item] = []) {
        self.title = title
        self.loc = loc
        self.json = json
        self.children = children
    }

    init?(title: String, content: Any) {
        // Check that the content is a dictionary and that it contains
        // locDict & jsonDict and both are dictionaries
        guard let content = content as? [String: Any],
            let loc = content["locDict"] as? [String: String],
            let json = content["jsonDict"] as? [String: String] else {
                return nil
        }

        // Check that both dictionaries contains same keys
        let locKeys = loc.keys.sorted()
        let jsonKeys = json.keys.sorted()
        guard locKeys == jsonKeys else {
            return nil
        }

        // Initialize top level item
        self.title = title
        self.loc = "locDict"
        self.json = "jsonDict"
        self.children = locKeys.map { key in
            // We can force unwrap here because we already checked that
            // both dictionaries contains same keys
            Item(title: key, loc: loc[key]!, json: json[key]!)
        }
    }
}
```

This structure is an example how you can do it, but there're lot of other
ways. It really depends on what you're planning to do here. You can switch
to an object (instead of a structure), ...

The key point here is that the `children` property is an ordered collection (array).

### View Controller

Add `items` property (again, an ordered collection = array).

```swift
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    private let items: [Item] = {
        // Map keysDetails to an array of our Item structures
        keysDetails.compactMap { (key: String, value: Any) in
            Item(title: key, content: value)
        }
    }()
}
```

### NSOutlineViewDataSource

As the name implies, data source provides just data. We already have the
`items` property, let's use it.

```swift
extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDataSource {
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
        if item == nil {
            // item == nil
            // We're being asked for the number of top level elements (kAddToBag, ...)
            return items.count
        }

        // Develop time (debug) - check that the item is really Item
        assert(item is Item);

        // item != nil
        // We're being asked for the number of children of an item
        return (item as! Item).children.count
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
        if item == nil {
            // item == nil
            // We're being asked for n-th (index) top level element
            return items[index]
        }

        // Develop time (debug) - check that the item is really Item
        assert(item is Item);

        // item != nil
        // We're being asked for n-th (index) child of an item
        return (item as! Item).children[index]
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
        // Develop time (debug) - check that the item is really Item
        assert(item is Item);

        // Item is expandable only if it has children
        return (item as! Item).children.count > 0
    }
}
```

### NSOutlineViewDelegate

Among other stuff, delegate provides cell view to display for particular item
and column.

```swift
extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        // Get the column identifier and our Item
        guard let columnIdentifier = tableColumn?.identifier,
            let item = item as? Item else {
                return nil
        }

        // Get a cell view identifier and an actual value we should display
        let cellViewIdentifier: String
        let stringValue: String

        switch columnIdentifier.rawValue {
        case "TitleColumn":
            cellViewIdentifier = "TitleCell"
            stringValue = item.title
        case "LocColumn":
            cellViewIdentifier = "LocCell"
            stringValue = item.loc
        case "JsonColumn":
            cellViewIdentifier = "JsonCell"
            stringValue = item.json
        default:
            return nil
        }

        // Make a view from the cell view identifier
        let view = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(cellViewIdentifier), owner: self) as? NSTableCellView
        // Update text field value
        view?.textField?.stringValue = stringValue
        return view
    }
}
```

### Sample project

- Create a new app in Xcode (macOS - Swift & Storyboard)
- Add the outline view

  - Set constraints
  - Connect delegate & datasource to the view controller
- Click on the outline view and set

  - Columns: 3
  - Uncheck Headers, Reordering
- Set 1st, 2nd and 3rd column identifier to `TitleColumn`, `LocColumn`, `JsonColumn`
- Set 1st, 2nd and 3rd column table cell view identifier to `TitleCell`, `LocCell`, `JsonCell`

[image]

Comment: Thank you @zrzka for helping me understand the implementation of delegate methods properly, these steps are working perfectly :)

Comment: @GaganaSAchar you're welcome. I did answer it, because it looks like you're a new to the AppKit and I didn't want to vote to close this question right away. But please, next time, show some effort, try to write some code, even not working one and we can iterate over it. SO is not a _homework service_ - show what you need & someone will code it. Treat this answer as rare exception.